# Installing React-Native Android in existing React Native iOS project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a fairly involved React-Native project in iOS and want to port it over to Android and test it's transferability. I have done the standard install instructions of:

'Install the latest JDK
Install the Android SDK:
On Mac: brew install android-sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
Open the Android SDK Manager (on Mac start a new shell and run android); in the window that appears make sure you check:
Android SDK Build-tools version 23.0.1
Android 6.0 (API 23)
Android Support Repository
Click "Install Packages"'

But I still do not see the Andriod directories in my existing app. Is there a way to get Android dependencies without doing 'react-native init AwesomeProj'?

Answer (score 2):

## [Adding Android to an existing React Native project](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#adding-android-to-an-existing-react-native-project)

If you already have a (iOS-only) React Native project and want to add Android support, you need to execute the following commands in your existing project directory:

Update the react-native dependency in your package.json file to the latest version

```
$ npm install
$ react-native android
```

Comment: Got this: $ react-native android
Command `android` unrecognized
Usage: react-native <command>

Commands:
  start: starts the webserver
  install: installs npm react components
  bundle: builds the javascript bundle for offline use
  new-library: generates a native library bridge

Comment: you'd run it without the $. The $ is just a convention to indicate that it should be run from the terminal window.